# Building drop-down-list in Laravel (without models)

Tags: drop-down-menu, view, laravel

I am trying to make a drop down list in Laravel with the select options being values from my database and I have some issues. In other tutorials in this site, doing drop down list inquires building the models for your database. I have not created model classes and I do not intend to.

Routes.php

```
Route::get("/user/charname", array(
    'as' => 'profile-character',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@dropDownList'
));
```

ProfileController.php

```
class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    public function dropDownList()
    {
        $list = DB::table('characters')->where('char_id', '128')->pluck('char_name');
        return View::make('layout.profile')->with('character_options',$list);
    }
}
```

In the profile.blade.php    (view)

```
<div class="selected_char">
    <form action="{{ URL::route('profile-character') }}" method="post">
        <li>
            {{ Form::select('character_options', $list ,Input::old('character_options')) }}
        </li>
    </form>
</div>
```

By doing this it says that $list from my view is undefined. Where do I define $list in the view and how will I carry $list from my Controller to the View because this line doesn't seem to do it's job

```
return View::make('layout.profile')->with('character_options',$list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$character_options` not `$list` in the View.

Comment: I have made the required modification in my code with {{ Form::select('character_options', $character_options ,Input::old('character_options')) }} . It makes perfect sense what you are saying, but I don't get it why it still doesn't work. It says now that character_options is undefined variable in profile.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

You actually specify that the variable should be 'character_options' in your `View::make()` call, so you need to refer to it as `$character_options`.

Additionally, `->lists('char_name')` is better than using `->pluck('char_name')` as it'll give you the full list. Pluck just returns the first item it finds.

Additionally to that, using `->lists('char_name', 'id')` gets you the list keyed by the `id` column, which would be useful if you were to use this list to determine IDs for a foreign key field. But no biggie if not.

Comment: Something like {{ Form::select('character_options', $character_options ,Input::old('character_options')) }} in my View?

Comment: Yeah that sounds reasonable to me, but from the look of your other comments that's not working for you. If you've actually pasted a simplified version of your controller or view code you could try to give more detail - it's possible something's interfering with the variable being available, but we can't see it due to you having removed some code for brevity. Maybe boil your controller and views down to the simplest form and work your way up - you'll usually see the one tiny issue that caused the big problem then.

Answer (score 0):

I have partially solved the issues by doing this in my view:

```
 {{ Form::select('list', DB::table('characters')->where('char_id', '128')->lists('char_name') ,Input::old('list')) }}
```

Personally I do not see it as a viable solution, but a temporary one

{{ Form::select('character_options', $character_options ,Input::old('character_options')) }}

Error: undefined variable character_options

{{ Form::select('character_options', $list ,Input::old('character_options')) }}
Error: undefined variable list

Maybe I do not understand how i send the variable from the Controller to the View.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `lists` as mentioned by @alexrussel. Do note that `View::make('layout.profile')->with('character_options',$list);`, here you are passing the variable `$character_options` with the value contained in the `$list` and `$list` will no longer be available to the view.

**ProfileController.php**

```
<?php

class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    public function dropDownList()
    {
        $list = DB::table('characters')->where('char_id', '128')->lists('char_name');
        return View::make('layout.profile')->with('character_options',$list);
    }
}
```

**profile.blade.php**

```
<div class="selected_char">
<form action="{{ URL::route('profile-character') }}" method="post">
    <li>
        {{ Form::select('character_options', $character_options ,Input::old('character_options')) }}
    </li>
</form>
```